# Android - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid item position 0(0). Item count:0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-6.0-marshmallow, target-sdk

I am getting this exception in my log -

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid item position 0(0). Item count:0
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4622)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
            at com.jivemap.app.CustomizedViews.MyLinearLayoutManager.measureScrapChild(MyLinearLayoutManager.java:66)
            at com.jivemap.app.CustomizedViews.MyLinearLayoutManager.onMeasure(MyLinearLayoutManager.java:30)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2614)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15318)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1061)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:599)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15318)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:704)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:597)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15318)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1061)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:599)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15318)
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1849)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1764)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1320)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1635)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2141)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1672)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1530)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1672)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1530)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1672)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1530)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13874)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
```

I am getting this error on the line -

```
View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
```

Here, in this method of custom LinearLayoutManager -

```
  private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {



        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);

        }
    }
```

Previously, it was working well.
I recently changed the targetSdkVersion to 23 (Marshmallow), and as well as the versions of support lib. May be the issue is for the same reason.

Please guide me, how to fix this.

Comment: did you somewhere use `notifyDataSetChanged` ?

Comment: No, I am not using notifyDataSetChanged anywhere.
but I am calling viewTreeObserver on RecyclerView,

Comment: Will it be affected if you use [`findViewByPosition`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findViewByPosition%28int%29) instead ?

Comment: no, I don't think. As the position I am getting there, in the method - **measureScrapChild** is 0

Comment: I guess, I must try to avoid getting 0

Comment: use findViewByPosition() on recyclerView.getLinearlayoutManager(). It will give the view at a particular index.

Comment: I don't have RecyclerView object inside **measureScrapChild()**.
What I have there is - object of RecyclerView.Recycler.
Thats why, I am unable to get LayoutManager. How to use **findViewByPosition** then.

Comment: You may know that `getViewForPosition` method should be used by `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` where `findViewByPosition()` method easily available.

Comment: let me post that method too. Hope, that will make you easy to understand.

Comment: added the method @ShreeKrishna. Please check, I don't have RecyclerView there.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra Where this method belongs ? Please reply fast And sorry to inform I am leaving now and in leave for 2 days..

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra This is `onMeasure`, not `measureScrapChild`..

Comment: It belongs to custom LinearLayoutManager class, I already told

Comment: @ShreeKrishna check my exception log, it will tell, first **onMeasure** will be called, which in turn calls **measureScrapChild**

Comment: @NarendraJi Did you find the answer for this ? I have the same problem, pl let us know how to solve this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I meet the same problem, and I find a better way to solve it.

call `setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);` in the constructor of your custom LayoutManager.

After API level 27 **setAutoMeasureEnabled() is deprecated**.
So just override this method in your Custom LinearLayoutManager

```
@Override
public boolean isAutoMeasureEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: After updating RecyclerView from v7:21.0.0 to v7:27.0.2 i faced this issue. By using the proposed solution it finally worked. They must have changed the default beahavior of the RecyclerView from v7:22. Thank you.

Comment: This method has been deprecated since v7:27.1.0. You should override `isAutoMeasureEnabled()` in your implementation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#setAutoMeasureEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved :)

Replacing

> compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'

to

> compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'

worked.

Not Sure, this is perfect solution or not, but it worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't work you need to compile with build tools 23.